# How to we get to this reformulation of the Picard iteration for a controlled differential equation in order to see the connection to signatures?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $L(\mathbb R^{d}, \mathbb R^{e})$ be the space of linear functions from $\mathbb R^{d}$ to $\mathbb R^{e}$. Consider $V: \mathbb R^{e} \to L(\mathbb R^{d},\mathbb R^{e})$, the control  $X:[a,b]\to \mathbb R^{d}$ and $Y: [a,b] \to \mathbb R^{e}$ and the controlled differential equation:
$$ 
dY_{t} = V(Y_{t})dX_{t}\quad Y_{a}=y \in \mathbb R^{e}
$$
Via the Picard iteration we obtain:
$$
\begin{align}
Y^{0}_{t} & = y \\
Y^{1}_{t} = y+\int_{a}^{t}V(Y_{s}^{0})dX_{s} &=\left(\int_{a}^{t}dV(X_{s})+I_{e}\right)(y)\label{1}\tag{*}\\
Y^{2}_{t}= y+\int_{a}^{t}V(Y_{s}^{1})dX_{s} &=\left(\int_{a}^{t}\int_{a}^{u}dV(X_{s})dV(X_{u})+\int_{a}^{t}dV(X_{s})+I_{e}\right)(y)\label{2}\tag{**}\\
&\ldots\\
&\ldots
\end{align}
$$

I do not understand how the last equalities in the lines \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} come about, for example in \eqref{1}, I only get:

$$y+\int_{a}^{t}V(y)dX_{s}=\left(I_{e}+\int_{a}^{t}V(\cdot)dX_{s}\right)(y)$$

So why/how is $\left(\int_{a}^{t}V(\cdot)dX_{s}\right)(y)=\left(\int_{a}^{t}dV(X_{s})\right)(y)$?